# How to parse AND store arguments in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am using argparse for parsing arguments in this fashion :

```
outputFile = ""
input

def getArguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Execute the given pig script and pipe the output to given  outFile.')
    parser.add_argument('-o','--outputFile', help='Output file where pig file execution output is stored.', required=True)
    input = parser.parse_args()
    print ("========================================")
    print ("Argument to the script")
    print ("outputFile = %s" % input.outputFile )
    return input
input = getArguments()
outputFile = input.outputFile
print ("outputFile = %s" % outputFile )
```

My question is,  is there a way a better AND/OR more compact way of writing parsing in this way ?

Note : I am especially trying to look for  binding of parsed argument to the variable in the file. I hope to not to use "input" variable every-time I access input-argument nor do I want to have explicit variable declared just to copy the parameters from the argument-string to a variable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters :  Sorry there was a typo when copy pasting. I am returning input. AND then there are bunch of lines doing essentially the following
arg1 = input.arg1

Comment: As a representative of the Pig related tags, Hey! It seems like you are doing this for a python wrapper. Feel free to open a more specific question in `Pig`, we need more questions on this topic.

Comment: @Ajeet: But what is wrong with `options.arg1`? There is no need to re-assign all the options to locals here. There is no real advantage to doing so.

Comment: Nothing wrong in options.arg1
I want to use  arg1 instead :options.arg1

Answer (score 0):

As @MartijinPieters points out in the comments, there is nothing wrong with `options.arg1`.  Firstly, I want to echo this. There isn't a very clean (or clear IMHO) way of doing what you are asking for.

---

What you'll need to do is convert the `options` object into a dictionary. This can be done using [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
opt_dict = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Then you'll have to load all the values in the dictionary into the locals. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650622/how-can-i-load-all-keys-from-a-dict-as-local-variables-a-better-aproach) that shows examples of how to do this. I like Ken's answer for its clarity:

```
for item in opt_dict.iteritems():
    eval('{0} = {1}'.format(*item))
```

But it allows for the possibility of dangerous input sneaking in. Also, this will have to be done outside of the `getArguments()` function.

**However, I agree that the accepted answer on the previously linked question is probably the best way of doing this, which is to use the opt_dict to update** `globals`.

**NOTE:** If you are doing this for a Pig python wrapper, like I suspect, then loading the the variables into the locals will actually be counter productive. The variables need to be passed into `bind` as a dictionary.

Comment: Using `eval()` is a terrible idea, really. If the OP needs *globals* (which is true for the sample), then a `globals().update(vars(parser.parse_args))` would suffice. And then confuse the hell out of everyone that has to ever read or maintain that code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, I just like the `eval` method because, IMO, it is more readable. I'll highlight the part of the answer where I mention it is a bad idea.